# AWS chalice error. How do I properly put my credentials in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chalice

Hi I'm trying to access serverless API. I got as far as creating virtual environments, activating it and puting my credentials in. Though when I try to deploy aws chalice, this is what i get:

```
Creating deployment package.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\cli\__init__.py", line 599, in main
    return cli(obj={})
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\cli\__init__.py", line 206, in deploy
    deployed_values = d.deploy(config, chalice_stage_name=stage)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\deployer.py", line 353, in deploy
    return self._deploy(config, chalice_stage_name)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\deployer.py", line 364, in _deploy
    plan = self._plan_stage.execute(resources)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\planner.py", line 139, in execute
    result = handler(resource)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\planner.py", line 195, in _plan_lambdafunction
    if not self._remote_state.resource_exists(resource):
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\planner.py", line 61, in resource_exists
    result = handler(resource)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\planner.py", line 94, in _resource_exists_lambdafunction
    return self._client.lambda_function_exists(resource.function_name)
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\awsclient.py", line 103, in lambda_function_exists
    client = self._client('lambda')
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\chalice\awsclient.py", line 708, in _client
    self._client_cache[service_name] = self._session.create_client(
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 831, in create_client
    client = client_creator.create_client(
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 83, in create_client
    client_args = self._get_client_args(
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 285, in _get_client_args
    return args_creator.get_client_args(
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py", line 99, in get_client_args
    endpoint = endpoint_creator.create_endpoint(
  File "c:\users\jerom\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 286, in create_endpoint
    raise ValueError("Invalid endpoint: %s" % endpoint_url)
ValueError: Invalid endpoint: https://lambda.New Jersey.amazonaws.com
```

does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Where did you get `https://lambda.New Jersey.amazonaws.com`?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you provided an invalid valid value for "Region" when storing your credentials.

The region name forms part of the URL when connecting to AWS services, which is why your code is trying to access `https://lambda.New Jersey.amazonaws.com`. (New Jersey is not a valid Region.)

To fix:

- Use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to update your credentials.
- In the **Region** field, provided a region code from the list of [AWS Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#regional-endpoints), such as `us-west-2` or `eu-west-2`.